# Intersecting dictionaries based on values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries (dict1,dict2) consisting of three keys (gene_expression, Metadata, pValues) each containing large datasets. I would like to compare and contrast those two dictionaries to create a separate dictionary with common elements where pValue was <=0.005.

If I try:

```
intersection=dict(dict1.items() & dict2.items())
```

I get

```
unhashable type: 'DataFrame'
```

Ideally I would like to actually subset the items from both dictionaries where value is <=0.005

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and make it possible for others to observe the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result. What do you mean by "consisting of three keys" together with "each containing large datasets"? Are the values large datasets? In what format/container? What is the functionality expected?

Answer (score 0):

Demonstrate that the error 'unhashable type: 'DataFrame'' appears when attempting to use a dataframe as a key. This is because dataframes are mutable and keys cannot be mutable.

```
dict1 = {0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7',
         8: '8', 9: '9'}
dict2 = {0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 50: '50', 60: '60', 70: '70',
         80: '80', 90: '90'}

intersection = dict(dict1.items() & dict2.items())
print(f'{intersection=}')
intersection = dict1.items() & dict2.items()
print(f'{intersection=}')

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.randint(5, 30, size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['random_numbers'])

print(df)
dict3 = {df: 100}
```

Comment: I checked it, but both of them are dictionaries.

Comment: `unhashable type: 'DataFrame'` probably means that a key in the new dictionary `intersection` is a dataframe. Try `intersection = dict1.items() & dict2.items()` and see if that works?

Comment: Nope, still get the same error. unhashable type: 'DataFrame'

Comment: I modified the example code to demonstrate that the error 'unhashable type: 'DataFrame'' appears when attempting to use a dataframe as a key. Without seeing the code that produces the error in the question, I am stuck. I guess we are left hoping someone will answer the question for us.